# Copy data from multiple excel sheets and append that to a single excel sheet using VBScript

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

The scenario is as follows:

1. I have an excel (.xls) file with data. (eg. **A.xls**)
2. The Data on this excel file are on a single worksheet (Sheet 1).
3. The number of columns in this file is fixed i.e. 8
4. However, the number of rows containing data may vary from time to time. (This file is updated by another program from time to time)
5. Now, I have another excel file (eg. **B.xls**) with similar type of data but not same as the contents of **A.xls**.
6. The number of columns in **B.xls** is 8 as well. However, the number of rows containing data are unknown.

I want to copy the contents of **A.xls**, **2nd row onwards** (**excluding the 1st row containing the column headers**) and append/paste the same to the B.xls file, without over-writing the existing data on B.xls.

With all these details in mind, I want to write a vbscript to automate this task.

Please help.

Thanks a lot, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs a lot of cleanup, but something like this should work.  I'll clean it up a bit and then make an edit.

```
Sub CopyRows()
  ' Choose the name of the Second Workbook and last column.
  ' It must be in the same directory as your First Workbook.
  secondWorkbook = "B.xls"
  lastColumn = "H"

  ' A couple more variables
  currentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.Name
  Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & secondWorkbook

  ' In the First Workbook, find and select the first empty
  ' cell in column A on the first Worksheet.
  Windows(currentWorkbook).Activate
  With Worksheets(1).Columns("A:A")
    Set c = .Find("", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
      ' Select and copy from A2 to the end.
      secondAddress = Replace(c.Address, "$A$", "")
      Range("A2:" & lastColumn & CStr(CInt(secondAddress) - 1)).Select
      Selection.Copy
    End If
  End With

  ' Activate the Second Workbook
  Windows(secondWorkbook).Activate
  With Worksheets(1).Columns("A:A")
    Set c = .Find("", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
      ' Select and paste the data from First Workbook
      Range(c.Address).Select
      ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

**Update**: That should do the trick.  I copied from the wrong workbook the first time around, too.  Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is something the Macro Recoder could have written for you. You would come out with different approach.

Turn on recording. Open A.xls and B.xls. Move down one row on a. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> then <kbd>→</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy your data. Switch back to B. <kbd>End</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste. Turn off recording.

You can record in Excel.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>R</kbd>

then <kbd>Home</kbd> key then <kbd>↑</kbd>. Stop recording.

Look what Excel wrote

```
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
```

or if you had of recorded Go To dialog

```
Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1"
```

or if you had of recorded <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>

```
Range("A1").Select
```

To convert to vbscript

Record the steps in excel macro recorder. You have to rewrite it a bit because it uses a type of syntax that vbs doesn't.

This applies (I don't have a medium9) `xlRangeAutoFormatAccounting4` in vba.

```
Selection.AutoFormat Format:=xlRangeAutoFormatAccounting4, Number:=True, _
    Font:=True, Alignment:=True, Border:=True, Pattern:=True, Width:=True
```

So first look up constants in vba's object browser. `xlRangeAutoFormatAccounting4 = 17`

Then look the function up in object browser and look at the bottom for the function definition,.

```
Function AutoFormat([Format As XlRangeAutoFormat = xlRangeAutoFormatClassic1], [Number], [Font], [Alignment], [Border], [Pattern], [Width])
```

So the vba becomes in vbs (and vbs works in vba) (and as you can see you can work out the correct way without needing to look the function up usually)

```
Selection.AutoFormat 17, True, True, True,True, True, True
```

So your code becomes

```
objXLWs.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Select.AutoFormat 17, True, True, True,True, True, True
```